# Android: WebView onReceivedHttpError does not return status code != 200

Tags: android, webview

I need to know if a webpage could be loaded or not with the android `WebView`. Ideally I would like to get the document status code and check if it's != 200. I did not find any method in the `WebViewClient` which supports it.

The one method which works somewhat is [#onReceivedHttpError](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onReceivedHttpError(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest,%20android.webkit.WebResourceResponse))

> Notify the host application that an HTTP error has been received from the server while loading a resource. HTTP errors have status codes >= 400. This callback will be called for any resource (iframe, image, etc), not just for the main page. Thus, it is recommended to perform minimum required work in this callback. Note that the content of the server response may not be provided within the errorResponse parameter.

```
 @Override
  public void onReceivedHttpError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceResponse errorResponse) {
  webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.de");
  super.onReceivedHttpError(view, request, errorResponse);
 }
```

But that one gets called as soon as something returns with a status code above 400 even if the web page is loaded for example a missing `.png`.

I am using this site as a reference test https://www.httpstatus.io/
The page loads sucessfully in the `WebView` but misses some files like `.js` and `.png` which calls `onReceivedHttpError` with a `404`.

How do I get the document status code with the `WebView`?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is no method to get the document status code. A workaround looks like this. Basically open a connection with the httpclient and check the status code there and then load it with the `WebView`

E.g.

```
  AndroidHttpClient httpClient = new AndroidHttpClient(url);
        httpClient.get(null, null, new AsyncCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(HttpResponse httpResponse) {
                if (httpResponse.getStatus() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    webView.loadUrl(url);
                } else {
                    webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Exception e) {
                webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
            }
        });
```

I am using the [Basic-Http-Client](https://github.com/turbomanage/basic-http-client) but the idea is the same with any other `httpClient`